# How do I reject a snapshot during recovery?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I'm currently attempting to implement snapshotting to an event sourced application using Akka Persistence. The strategy that I'm attempting to take here is:

- Save a snapshot every X events
- Maintain a `schemaVersion` property on my state object. The purpose of the `schemaVersion` is to allow me to evolve/migrate my state if I change the way I'm replying my events.
- During recovery, if I receive a SnapshotOffer whose `state.schemaVersion` is less than my current schema version, discard that snapshot and replay events from the beginning
- Delete all snapshots earlier than my latest valid snapshot after recovery complete

However, I'm finding that I'm not able to discard snapshots during recovery. If there is a snapshot in the snapshot store, earlier events will not be offered to me.

I'm having a hard time reading up on how this should be handled. What's the proper approach here?

Comment: I'm honestly unsure this is even possible as stated.  You might have to work around this, by setting a "reject" flag during recovery, throwing out all the recovery data, and then doing the rewrite-and-replay in post-start, when you have a bit more flexibility...

Comment: I'm surprised that there aren't more people talking about this. Surely, evolving states must be one of the concerns of event sourcing, right?

Comment: Sure, but that's not the usual way of dealing with it.  In general, folks use Persistence with a forward-compatible serialization format, that is friendly to schema evolution.  I evolve my schema all the time, but I never reject the old events or snapshots -- I just make sure the new schema is capable of handling the older data intelligently...

Comment: That's 99% of how I anticipate this is going to work. However, I want to make sure there's a way to recover from an incompatible snapshotted state; e.g. what if if there's some bug in the journal replay logic that produced an incorrect state?

Comment: In that case, I suspect you fall back to my suggestion above: you set a "reject" flag, and replay manually after recovery.  It's an edge case, and I think has to be treated as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one thing I don't get, what is the state object? And from where it's getting the `schemaVersion`? Isn't the state exactly the state of your actor that is reconstructed from the snapshot / events?

In any case, you can't delete and/or skip a snapshot once it's offered. Instead, you can do the following:

1. add a config `drop-snapshot` (defaults to `false`)
2. on `preStart`

   ```
   override def preStart(): Unit = {
      super.preStart()
      if (dropSnapshot) deleteSnapshots(SnapshotSelectionCriteria.Latest)
   }
   ```
3. override `recovery` method

   ```
   override def recovery = {
      if (dropSnapshot) {
        Recovery(fromSnapshot = SnapshotSelectionCriteria.None)
      } else {
        Recovery(fromSnapshot = SnapshotSelectionCriteria.Latest)
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: The `state` object is the actor's internal state that I'm building via replaying events.

Hm. Using configuration isn't too bad of an idea. I wouldn't want it to simply be a boolean, as on my next deploy I might want to be restoring from snapshot.

Comment: However, I can determine whether to drop snapshots based off a timestamp in my config file or something.